# SELF JOIN /SUBQUERIES/SSIS performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hi I have three tables

```
Wrk_Order ,Wrk_Info,Wrk_Driver
```

all the three have DFirstName,DLastName,DUsername columns . I want to anonymise them

What I did is I have got distinct of each three columns in all the three table and loaded into lookup table as 
Table Name :LKP_driverinfo 
 Columns   :[DriverInfo,DriverAnonInfo]

DriverInfo column will have data as follows

```
SELECT Distinct DFirstName FROM Wrk_Order 
UNION 
SELECt DISTINCT DLastName FROM WRk_Order
UNION 
SELECt DISTINCT DUsername FROM WRk_Order

UNION 

SELECT Distinct DFirstName FROM Wrk_Info
.
.

.
```

Similarly for rest two tables

DriverAnonInfo : will have anonymized value of Driverinfo

I need to update DFirstName,DLastName,DUsername of all the three tables to anonymised information [DriverAnonInfo] from Lookup table  LKP_driverinfo

whats the best way to achieve this self-join or inner queries or using SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to create a sort of EAV model with your driver info, but you do not seem to keep any references for the originating tables.

Perhaps you can try adding 3 more columns to your driverinfo table, to hold the id of the table that the value comes from. That way you can directly update or join entries in the tables.